# Unable to get println working in Grouped Integer Range map function

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I am experimenting with below code:

```
def TestRun(n: Int): Unit = {
      (1 to n)
        .grouped(4)
        .map(grp => { println("Group length is: " + grp.length)})
    }

TestRun(100)
```

And I am a bit surprised that I am not able to see any output of `println` after executing the program. Code compiled successfully and ran, but without any expected output.

Kindly point me what mistake I am doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason there is no output is that `Range` gives an `Iterator` which is *lazy*. This means that it won't create any data until it is asked. Likewise the `grouped` and `map` methods also return a lazy `Iterator`, so the result is a `Iterator` that will return a set of values *only when asked*. `TestRun` never asks for the data, so it is never generated.

One way round this is to use `foreach` rather than `map` because `foreach` is *eager* (the opposite of *lazy*) and will take each value from the `Iterator` in turn.

Another way would be to force the `Iterator` to become a concrete collection using something like `toList`:

```
def TestRun(n: Int): Unit = {
  (1 to n)
    .grouped(4)
    .map(grp => { println("Group length is: " + grp.length)})
    .toList
}

TestRun(100)
```